# Bound Listbox with Multiselect=NONE not saving to table

Tags: listbox, ms-access-2010

I have a form containing Cbo_Vendor where the user selects a Vendor (based on a list from a linked spreadsheet that lists Vendors & PN's).  This selection is used to filter 2 select queries for separate listboxes: (Qry_Parts) to derive a list of PN's for the vendor and (Qry_Team) to determine who the buyer is for that vendor.

Qry_Team has 2 fields - Vendor & Buyer, and is tied to a separate linked spreadsheet that lists Vendors & Buyers.  The criteria for Vendor is

```
[Forms]![Summary_Form]![Cbo_Vendor]
```

I have a listbox to display the buyer's name from Qry_Team.  The row source for List_Buyer is

```
SELECT [Qry_Team].[Buyer] FROM Qry_Team;
```

And only one name should populate in the list box.

I have been unsuccessful in getting the Buyer's name to save in my table.

I have VBA code to requery for the listbox once Cbo_Vendor is updated.  This works.
I also have code to auto-select the one name that appears in the listbox.  This also works.
I have tried setting up the "Buyer' field in my table as normal text and as a lookup field based on Table/Query (using the same SELECT statement as the listbox on my form and also by leaving it blank).

```
Private Sub Cbo_Vendor_AfterUpdate()
  Me.List_Buyer.Requery
  List_Buyer.Selected(0) = True
End Sub
```

Regardless of what I try, I cannot get the buyer's name to save to my summary table unless I physically click on the already selected name.  How do I get this to save without requiring the user to user to select it again?

Comment: Confusing problem description. Details that don't help describe the problem. How do you "save the buyer's name" - you don't mention any code, or even if the form is bound to a table, or if a form field is bound to a controlsource field in a table.

Comment: I did show code and the criteria for my queries.  The form is bound to TblSummary.  The form field is bound to "Buyer" within that table. I am new here, so please be patient while I try to learn what info is relevant for someone to offer advice. I try to include any info related to the form and what I am trying to accomplish. Any constructive criticism and help offered is GREATLY appreciated. I am seriously 15 yrs out of practice in VBA coding.

Comment: Instead of `List_Buyer.Selected(0) = True` try assigning the value directly by `Me!List_Buyer = List_Buyer.ItemData(0) `

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: Excellent - Can I add it as an answer that you can mark as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes it hard to figure out how you're updating the fields - and what controls are matched to fields. Ideally a list of controls with their properties (controlsource, controlname and any sql that goes along with list queries) would make it easier.

Sometimes even adding a screenshot of your form with the affected controls makes it easier to visualize.

Saying that, it did make it easier to guess the problem after you added your comments:

> The form is bound to TblSummary. The form field is bound to "Buyer"
>   within that table.

Instead of `List_Buyer.Selected(0) = True`

try assigning the value directly by `Me!List_Buyer = List_Buyer.ItemData(0)`

The value does not get directly assigned when you used the `.Selected(index)` property